# JacksonParser: Cannot find file or directory

Tags: android, json, jackson, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to run a simple jackson parsor but when i am trying to get data fron Json file, its telling  "\user.json(no such file or directory)".

JacksonParser:

```
public class JacksonParser {

    static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public static User mapping() throws JsonParseException,
            JsonMappingException, IOException {

        User user = mapper.readValue(new File("user.json"), User.class);
        if (user == null)
            return user;
        return user;
    }

}
```

User.java(pojo class):

```
public class User {
    public enum Gender {
        MALE, FEMALE
    };

    public static class Name {
        private String _first, _last;

        public String getFirst() {
            return _first;
        }

        public String getLast() {
            return _last;
        }

        public void setFirst(String s) {
            _first = s;
        }

        public void setLast(String s) {
            _last = s;
        }
    }

    private Gender _gender;
    private Name _name;
    private boolean _isVerified;

    public Name getName() {
        return _name;
    }

    public boolean isVerified() {
        return _isVerified;
    }

    public Gender getGender() {
        return _gender;
    }

    public void setName(Name n) {
        _name = n;
    }

    public void setVerified(boolean b) {
        _isVerified = b;
    }

    public void setGender(Gender g) {
        _gender = g;
    }

}
```

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        User user = null;

        try {
            user = JacksonParser.mapping();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getStackTrace();
        }

        textview.setText("" + user.getName() + " " + user.getGender() + " " + user.isVerified());
    }

}
```

user.json:

```
{
    "name" : { "first" : "Joe", "last" : "Sixpack" },
    "gender" : "MALE",
    "verified" : false,
}
```

UPDATE: I corrected the previous error but stuck with the next one.. Its telling "\user.json(no such file or directory)" I have updated the question.

Comment: Please post a full stacktrace. *print* the stacktrace: you have `getStackTrace()` in your `catch` which *won't* print it. use `e.printStackTrace();`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not related to Jackson at all, this is more a Java general question. When you do new File("user.json"), this create a relative file path: it is relative to your application working directory. That file isn't present in your current working directory, so Java can't find the file. You need to provide a more complete path the the file for it to work.